# IIS 7.5 .NET Shared DLL Access is Denied Error

Tags: .net, dll, iis-7.5, access-denied

Preface: We have load balanced web servers, and a restful wcf api web app.
In our web app, we have several references added via nuget packages, or by other visual studio projects.  Last week I added a new project (PLEGateway), which is a data layer into our system, along with some API calls into a 3rd party system.
The code (bin) is published to a file server, and has proper permissions so the web servers can see it.

After deployed, I ran into the dreaded 
**Could not load file or assembly 'PLEGatewayCore, Version=1.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.** error.

The odd thing is, it appears to only throw this error intermittently.  Meaning it'll work, come back after awhile and try again and it'll fail.  Wait awhile, come back and it'll work all a sudden.  "awhile" is defined from anywhere like 5 minutes, to overnight, so just trying to execute it via postman randomly.

I went through google and other SO questions on the issue and they all seemed to point to permission issues on the Temporary asp.net folders.  I verified permissions are setup correct.  The app pool **IS** enabled for 32-bit applications.  All other methods in the web app work, and only those that reference any functions in this dll cause errors.

I finally started looking at Process explorer for our W3wp.exe file for this application pool and when I look at the .NET assemblies tab, one server has my dll loaded, and the other does not when looking at the non-shared AppDomain section.

Overall my question is:  Why does one server load the dll's, while the other server doesn't, when they IIS config is also pulling from the same location (shared config)?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that both webservers point to an other server, being the fileserver which has de bin folder and other website files?

Comment: yes, both web servers point to another server which is a file server.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 webservers A and B. Both are configured to load their binaries in the bin folder from a shared fileserver.

You get an access denied error because IIS locks these files when loaded. This means that only one of the webservers succeeds in loading its binaries.

The reason the error occurs intermittently depends of by which server your webrequest gets served which gets decided by the loadbalancer and its loadbalancing algorithm in use.

Put the binaries on each separate webserver to prevent a single point of failure for these files.

Comment: Ok, I'm just confused because we have other dll's in this project and we've never experienced this before.  Can you reference the location for a dll in the web.config file somehow?

Comment: No, that is not possible; by convention they must be in the bin folder (or GAC). But to improve the faulttollerance, ensure that each webserver has as less possible dependencies on other servers. We had 3 standalone webservers, with only the database server in common and even no shared config.